# Editing an Xml file

Tags: c#, asp.net

What are the different ways for editing an Xml file in .Net without using LINQ.

The following activity needs to be done.

1. Changing an InnerText of an element.
2. Changing an Attribute in Xml.

Regards,

Sachin K

Answer (score 6):

The most hardcore way will be treating XML document as a string and doing purely string manipulations (possibly with regexes) a-la `xml.Replace("<x></x>", "<x>foo</x>")`.

More reliable is an good old [`XmlDocument`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.aspx).

Comment: +1 for nearly making my heart stop ... please use <irony></irony> tags the next time ... XmlDocument is the way to go.

Comment: Can you go little deep with XmlDocument

Answer (score 0):

Create your object to deserialize the xml change the value of the variable in the object then serialize object to xml.